# Can i share a mongoose connection between my Lambda functions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I'm on an AWS StepFunction with some lambdas functions.

These functions will connect to the same database, but since they are different lambdas, it create a new connection every time

I use Serverless and serverless-middlewares to create the connection before lambda start and stop connection after the end of lambda.

But the problem is, even if it cuts the connection, when i run my Step function, it create a lot of connections (more than 300-400)

I wanted to know if there is a way to have a uniq connection for the entire Step Function, which could be used by all Lambda functions in

If you need more details, don't hesitate to ask for

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, but each lambda can (and should) keep its own connection alive.

Comment: @luk2302 So there is no way to create a connection at beginning and tell my functions to use the existing connection ?
My lambdas create a connection before running and close it when it has finished its work, it's not a good practice ?

Comment: You can instantiate these connections outside the event handler and then reuse to avoid recreating with each invocation. Because each execution environment is independent, you can't share across those, but you can share between invocations that use the same execution environment.

Comment: See the related note in the Lambda docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html. See "Take advantage of execution environment reuse to improve the performance of your function."

Comment: @JustinCallison My connections to my Mongo database is not initiate in the lambda handler. I use serverless-middleware plugin to initiate a connection before the lambda run, it's in another file